# loading page in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```html
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="ajaxform"></div>`

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



         <ul id="accordion" style="   margin-bottom: -1px;">
                    <li>cms</li>
                                     <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="defaults">Defaults</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="connections">Connections</a></li>

        </ul>
                        </ul>



  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".defaults").click(function(){
            $("#ajaxform").load("defaults.htm");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".connections").click(function(){
            $("#ajaxform").load("connections.html");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

i want to load another page in my div but i want do this by one function not like above one by one

### Heading ##  i want to load another page in my div but i want do this by one function not like above one by one

### Heading ##  i want to load another page in my div but i want do this by one function not like above one by one

### Heading

i want to load another page in my div but i want do this by one function not like above one by one

### Heading

Comment: Indent your code for Christ's sake.

Comment: @gsamaras my question is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        var link = $(this).attr("class") + ".htm";

        $("#ajaxform").load(link);
    });
});
```

Comment: i try it but it dosen't work

Comment: this works for me, but i just noticed you are using .htm for one file and .html for another, hence why you may be having an issue